# Self joining and sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, table_one, where records can be a child or a parent of another record.

I am trying to get for each record in TABLE_ONE the SUM of a column (points) contained in an attached record (users).

I tried several things like self joining or even with a RECURSIVE CTE in Postgres but without any success.

In the following table, record 3 is a child of record 1.

TABLE_ONE

```
+------------------+
|ID|NAME |PARENT_ID|
+------------------+
|1 |name1|         |
+------------------+
|2 |name2|         |
+------------------+
|3 |name3|1        |
+------------------+
```

TABLE_TWO

```
+-----------------------+
|ID|TABLE_ONE_ID|USER_ID|
+-----------------------+
|1 |1           |1      |
+-----------------------+
|2 |1           |2      |
+-----------------------+
|3 |3           |3      |
+-----------------------+
|4 |2           |4      |
+-----------------------+
```

TABLE USERS

```
+---------+
|ID|POINTS|
+---------+
|1 |100   |
+---------+
|2 |200   |
+---------+
|3 |100   |
+---------+
|4 |50    |
+---------+
```

Excepted result:

```
+---------------+
|ID|NAME |POINTS|
+---------------+
|1 |name1|400   |
+---------------+
|2 |name2|50    |
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the parent totals:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SUM(POINTS) as POINTS
FROM TABLE_ONE T1
JOIN TABLE_TWO T2 on T1.ID = T2.TABLE_ONE_ID
JOIN TABLE_USERS U on T2.USER_ID = U.ID
WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL --assuming those are nulls in table_one, not ''
GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

Then get the child totals for each parent:

```
SELECT SUM(POINTS) as POINTS, PARENT_ID
FROM TABLE_ONE T1
JOIN TABLE_TWO T2 on T1.ID = T2.TABLE_ONE_ID
JOIN TABLE_USERS U on T2.USER_ID = U.ID
WHERE PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY PARENT_ID
```

Then combine the queries and add up the `POINTS`:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.NAME, PARENT_POINTS + COALESCE(CHILD_POINTS,0) as POINTS
FROM (SELECT T1.ID, NAME, SUM(POINTS) as PARENT_POINTS
      FROM TABLE_ONE T1
      JOIN TABLE_TWO T2 on T1.ID = T2.TABLE_ONE_ID
      JOIN TABLE_USERS U on T2.USER_ID = U.ID
      WHERE PARENT_ID IS NULL --assuming those are nulls in table_one, not ''
      GROUP BY ID, NAME) P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(POINTS) as CHILD_POINTS, PARENT_ID
           FROM TABLE_ONE T1
           JOIN TABLE_TWO T2 on T1.ID = T2.TABLE_ONE_ID
           JOIN TABLE_USERS U on T2.USER_ID = U.ID
           WHERE PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY PARENT_ID) C on P.ID = C.PARENT_ID
```

A couple notes:

- The derived tables are important to ensure the parent to child join is a 1 to 1, otherwise you'll get duplicates
- You need a `LEFT JOIN` between the two so you don't lose childless parents, and you need `NULL` handling for the `POINTS` because of that (ie `COALESCE`)